# Forcing English exception messages

Tags: exception, localization, xsd, schema

When XML schema validation fails .Net throws some exception. Based on parsing this exception I know how to do some stuff. The problem is that this exception is localized, e.g. on a Japanese machine it is in Japanese.

- I do not want to build my application so it will parse every error in any language.
- I am an add-in to some other system so I do not want to change the locale (unless something is *totally* clean).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to parse the exception in the first place? The typical exception has attributes that tell you enough about it so that you don't need to parse the textual error message. Or are you only dealing with the *output* of the parser?

Comment: You shouldn't need to touch the string version of the exception. That's for the benefit of the user. The program has other means of checking the details of the exception.

Comment: This is not the case with xml validation errors. While they give me the position if the error in the schema, the only indication of what the error is is in the message.